# FadeIn effect on text

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fade

I've got this divs:

```
<div id="maintext">
        <div>
        <span>This is Photoshop's</span>
        <span>version  of Lorem</span>
        <span>Ipsum. Proin gravida</span>
        <span>nibh vel velit</span>
        <span>auctor aliquet. Aenean</span>
        <span>Psollicitudin, lorem quis</span>
        <span>bibendum auctor.</span>       
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i want, this spans get fadein effect. How can i do this?

Comment: fadein all together or in sequential way?

Comment: to fade it in, it has to be un-visible first. so you could change your css to:  `#maintext { display: none; }`

Comment: The yacht sit doesn't work on my phone, so I can't see what you are after. Also this can be done in a few different ways. Joy has shown you how to fade in the whole lot at once using jQuery's animation api, but it can also be done using CSS3 transitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need to show all elements together you could simpy hide and apply a `fadeIn()` to `#maintext > div` element instead of applying a fadeIn for every single `span` element

otherwise if you need a sequential fadeIn take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FUZwL/

```
$('#maintext span').hide().each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 200).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, its working. I will accept this answer after 3 min. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('#maintext span').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Or you can set your `spans` to `display:none;` using css and then [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) using jQuery.

```
#maintext span{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: You could also "nest" the methods like this `$('#maintext span').hide().fadeIn('slow');`. It's a cleaner approach, although it's better to set display:none in css if you can

Answer (score 0):

If your `<span>` are not visible, and you can use jQuery :

```
$("#maintext > div > span").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

to fadein all the span in order use **callbacks**:

```
function fadein(obj){
 obj.fadeIn('normal', function(){ 
  var next = (obj).next(); if (next.length>0) fadein(next); 
 });
}
$("#maintext span:first");
```